# Error with passing a function that outputs a fractional as an argument, but not with passing float directly

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that takes a number and a list and if the maximum number in the list and the input number are divisible, then return the result plus 1, but if it's not divisible then return the ceiling of the result

I have code that works as follows:

```
maxDiv n xs 
   | maximum xs `mod` n == 0 = ((maximum xs `div` n) + 1)
   | otherwise = ceiling (1.8)
```

the problem is that when I replace the 1.8 with

```
((maximum xs) / n)
```

I get an error, which I'll post below. I'ved tried taking it into a separate named function, as well as the taking it along with the ceiling part into a separate function, such as

```
helper n xs = ceiling ((maximum xs) / n)
length' n xs | maximum xs `mod` n == 0 = ((maximum xs `div` n) + 1) | otherwise = helper n xs
```

but I still get the same error.

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance (Show b, Show a) => Show (Either a b)
      -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
    instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    ...plus 23 others
    ...plus 43 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I've looked at the typing, and they all seem to be fractionals, what am I getting wrong / what would be a way around this?

Comment: It looks like you are mixing `/` with `div`, but `div` is used for `Integral` types, whereas `(/)` is used for `Fractional` numbers, and a type that is a member of both would be a bit "strange".

Comment: Doesn't the code in your first branch (```maximum xs `div` n + 1```) already return the ceiling of the division? Why branch at all, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing the "`Integral`" world with the "`Fractional`" world here. Indeed, [**`div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:div) and [**`mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod), are working with types that are `Integral`, whereas [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) works with items that are a type that are members of the `Fractional` typeclass.

Although, strictly speaking, one can make a type in Haskell that is both `Integral`, and `Fractional`, the two worlds have not that much in common. Furthermore we do not need that anyway. If you want to calculate the ceiling of `a/b`, you can calculate that with `div (a+b-1) b`. We can even use `div (a+b) b` here, since you want to add `+1` if it is divisable:

```
maxDiv :: (Integral a, Foldable t) => a -> t a -> a
maxDiv n xs = div (maximum xs + n) n
```